# Can't call "address" in the ABI

Tags: solidity, javascript, abi

for some reason I can't properly call the address in an abi file.  Here's the relevant JSON:

```
 "networks": {
    "1670104619050": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x270A4a133f5f37CC07E5c4F1e7F120Cbc50CBC3d",
      "transactionHash": "0x3e0004e99f1112fb0eeb03ec4128e5b2f3b7cb37bea0c2636a2104aef3ae5f50"
    }
  },
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
const IArbitrage = require('../build/contracts/Arbitrage.json')
const arbitrage = new web3.eth.Contract(IArbitrage.abi, IArbitrage.networks[1].address);
```

And here's the error:

```
/Users/Me/trading_bot-master/helpers/initialization.js:22
const arbitrage = new web3.eth.Contract(IArbitrage.abi, IArbitrage.networks[1].address);
                                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot-master/helpers/initialization.js:22:80)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot-master/bot.js:8:67)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

So far I have tried the following:

1. exchange .address for .transactionHash.  This failed with the exact same error (this was to confirm that address wasn't the problem, but something else that I haven't pinpointed yet.)
2. I also played with the networks[1] element, as there is only one object in the networks array so, theoretically, it should be `networks[0]`, `networks` or `.networks.1670104619050.address`

Comment: Did you try to console.log your address to see what you where getting out of it?

Comment: I forgot to write that one down, but yes, same error.  I'm fairly sure it's because I'm not correctly calling it though

Comment: Also, if I just do ```console.log(IArbitrage.networks[1]);```

I get this error: ```Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/Users/TrentKennelly/trading_bot-master/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:297:15) ```
(goes on from there)

Comment: Try different console.log until you retrieve that address for sure. Try console.log(IArbitrage.networks[1670104619050].address). Let me know if this work, I will create a proper answer so you can mark it as valid and get more visibility if someone else gets the same problem

Comment: console.log(IArbitrage.networks[1670104619050].address) printed the address!  However, when I plug it back into ```const arbitrage``` I'm still getting the error as you see in my last comment.  It's making me think there really is something wrong with the address itself.  Any other causes that you can foresee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part... I was working in ganache and somehow missed actually running the script on Infura ... several times...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x270A4a133f5f37CC07E5c4F1e7F120Cbc50CBC3d), I can see there is nothing at the address in your networks object. It is optional, so try to run this without declaring an address in the parameters passed to the

`new web3.eth.Contract([...])`

call. Or, check that this address is correct.

Read the docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html)

Comment: Thanks for this!  To clarify (maybe I left this out) I'm using this in a sandbox via Ganache, so I'm not surprised you wouldn't see it on etherscan.  That said, you're right that when I bring up the contract on etherscan there appears to be nothing there at all.  will see if I can confirm the address and update